# How is event peeking implemented by JIT-compilers of different process virtual machines?

Tags: javascript, java, virtual-machine, smalltalk, jit

**Note:** This question is posed to VM implementors of languages like Smalltalk, Self, Javascript, Java, C#, etc.

A usual functionality brought by the JIT compiler is automatic peeking of system events. This is used both for handling UI events and for triggering GC.

Usually this event peeking consists of doing a check at frame building (when methods are invoked) and at loop backjumps. I wondered,

> what are the different ways of implementing this check? What are their advantages and disadvantages? Do you know of any paper describing these techniques?
>
> Could you tell how it is implemented in a specific VM? (Pharo, HPS, HotSpot, V8, SpiderMonkey, CLR)

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, I guess each implementation does some variation of the following:

- Assigning a hardware register specifically for counting, and peeking when it reaches some threshold. *Upsides: the check is very fast. Downsides: you loose a register that could be better used, the count can be imprecise/meaningless.*
- Having a timer that is signaled periodically (how would it be implemented?) and then:

  - Moving a `stack_limit` variable that is then checked at frame building and backjumps
  - Marking the stack read-only or not accessible at hardware level (i.e. paging), so that frame building fails and adding a write to stack before backjumps. **Edit**: *Upsides: writing to memory is faster than reading because of data dependencies. Downsides: If the counter is triggered very frequently the check gets slower because page-fault catching is slow. Safepoints are polluted: any instruction that uses the stack after the page is marked will trigger the check, and that instruction may or may not be a safepoint*

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it, as you and @melkyades mention, is to allocate some register (e.g., `EBX`), usually initialized from the image to some maximum value. The JIT then inlines, at every nativized method, code that decrements the counter both at the beginning of the method and at every backjump (`#whileTrue:/False:`) occurring in it (BTW, this is why there is a backjump bytecode.) This code, when the counter becomes zero, checks three things: (1) whether there are any OS events to peek, (2) the state of the Object memory (which could end up triggering some GC action) and (3) the stack pointer (to anticipate an end-of-stack condition.)

One interesting trick that can be implemented goes on the lines of:

```
@1: call CheckEventsEtc
    ...
    cmp ESP, [TOS]
    dec EBX
    jbe @1
```

Given that `dec` doesn't modify the Carry flag the `jbe` instruction will jump to the checking routine if `ESP` becomes too small or if the counter at `EBX` becomes zero. If any of these conditions happens the checking routine will have to discern the cause and act accordingly.

Comment: would it be possible in this scheme to add a heartbeat thread that changes `[TOS]` and avoids using `EBX`?

Comment: @melkyades The system is perfectly responsive when the counter is initialized to 8 K. This means that the heartbeat should tick every 8 K messages or so. Therefore, some experimentation should be made to confirm that the context switch would be fast enough when compared to the almost negligible dec EBX. At a minimum it looks like it is an approach worth trying.